# Validate input array form with jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

How can i validate x inputs with name array like init_date[] with this plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/?

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        year:{required:true,number:true},
        type:{required:true},
        init_date:{required:true,date:true}
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation covers this.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

[Here's how to do it.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

Comment: Thanks, thats it, but it has very strange behaviors. The message appers only in the first input but the other ones also are validating but without error message...

Comment: @returnvoid: Because they all have the same field name. Technically speaking this _should not be the case_ in HTML and Javascript; it's just a hack for PHP that sort-of works in user-agents. You could give the elements explicit "array keys" by calling them `init_date[0]`, `init_date[1]` etc..

Comment: Thanks, it works: <input name="init_date[0]" /> and in the validation rules : {"init_date[0]":{required:true}} √√√

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom validation using Validator.addMethod(), I think it's not possible to apply validation based on names, you can validate a group of input elements using classes but not names.